# Python pandas dataframe: find the row which E column is 1 and A column is the largest, in case of ties, consider the largest of B, of C, of D column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an example dataframe listed as below. Because we need to choose from the rows which E column is 1, so the result should be among the first 4 rows. Choosing from which A column is the largest,  we have the first 3 rows. So we need to see among those which B column is the largest. Since we have a tie again, we should see the column C and find the largest. Finally we get the first column.

```
A   B   C   D   E
4   4   3   1   1   
4   2   0   0   1
4   4   1   1   1
3   0   0   0   1
5   0   0   1   0
```

So the desired output is like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E
4   4   3   1   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a combination of filtering and sorting:

```
res = df.loc[df['E'] == 1]\
        .sort_values(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ascending=False)\
        .head(1)

print(res)

   A  B  C  D  E
0  4  4  3  1  1
```